# React.js: I used setstate but it still can't rerender at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I have a list has many objects in it, like this:

```
[{id: 3, kategori: 'Kultur', name: 'Topkapı Sarayı',},{id: 5, kategori: 'Diger',name: 'Topkapı Sarayı', description: "xxxx"},]
```

and I want to return  objects of this list one by one on a card by (prev, next) buttons. so I created a counter and defined the increment (for next button) and reduce(for prev button) functions. Then I used this counter as index of the list. Finally I mapped this list like that:

```
this.viwedList = [ myList()[this.state.counter] ].map((tur) => (
            <CreatContent
            
                turName={tur.name}
                img={tur.img}
                country={tur.country}
                increment={this.increment}
                reduce={this.reduce}
            />
        ));
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                mainContent: this.viwedList
            };
        });
```

When I click on the prev and next buttons, the counter value increases and decreases. The main problem is that the displayed object does not change instantly, when I click on another category (list) and then return to the same card, then it changes.

> [first img of issua][1] [second img of issua][2] [last img of
> issua][3]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjzRf.jpg   [2]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tCVA.jpg   [3]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqS2E.jpg

Comment: How are you getting that list of objects? Can you post more of your actual code?

Answer (score 1):

When you render objects from an array, they need to have a unique `key` property. This lets React keep track of them, so it can know what things need to be updated on a new render.

Without a key, React may fail to update the components, as it fails to recognize that they have changed, which is the behavior you're seeing.

You can read more in [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).